# How to save the cell values returned by GoogleFinance( ) API in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am trying to download 1 year price data for all NSE stocks in google sheets using Google Finance API.
I just want the API to run only once (not on each sheet load)and populate the data. I want to save the data. I tried to copy paste the data into another sheet, but I get error telling max cells have reached.
Is there a way to run google finance api only once and have it run only on manual trigger instead of sheet load ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the formula you are using at least. And before doing so read through [how-to-ask-a-good-question-in-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)